# RestAssured - JsonPath filter a matching Object's properties from an array of objects, given a filter criteria

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am writing an integration test to my microservice using rest assured. I have a Json payload like this which is returned from it.

```
{
   "sessionQuestions":[
      {
         "id":1272,
         "sessionId":1146,
         "questionId":"1002",
      },
      {
         "id":1273,
         "sessionId":1146,
         "questionId":"1004",
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to find the id of a sessionquestion given the questionId value. Then I need to compare them in my assertion. I am having hard time fetching the id off of a sessionQuestion given the questionId value. I am using JsonPath to get this thing done. And here's my Json path expression.

```
new JsonPath(response).get("$.sessionQuestions[?(@.questionId=='1002')].id");
```

This throws an error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '[' @ line 1, column 45.
   nRootObject.$.sessionQuestions[?(@.quest
                                 ^

1 error

   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I tried the same Json path expression in this online [evaluator](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/), which works fine. I am using `json-path-2.9.0.jar`

What I am doing wrong here? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of JsonPath do you use? I use [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0).

And the code which works for your case is:

```
JsonPath.parse(response).read("$.sessionQuestions[?(@.questionId=='1002')].id").toString();
```

And try with this JSON:

```
{
   "sessionQuestions":[
      {
         "id":1272,
         "sessionId":1146,
         "questionId":"1002"
      },
      {
         "id":1273,
         "sessionId":1146,
         "questionId":"1004"
      }
   ]
}
```

Edit: If you are using this dependancy (json-path-2.9.0), you have to do it like this:

```
from(response).getList("sessionQuestions.findAll { it.questionId=='1002' }.id").toString();
```

and you have to import from like this:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.from;
```

Comment: No luck. Updated the question with the Json path version which I am using. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not have the `parse` and `read` methods.

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to be more specific to your upcoming posts :) Also take a look here https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage

Comment: Thanks for the solution. `from(response).getList("sessionQuestions.findAll { it.questionId=='1002' }.id").toString();` helped me when I'm directly using rest-assured's jsonpath. Jayway's jsonpath is different than the rest-assured one's, hence it leads to more complexity.

Comment: @CMM this is very helpful reply from you, i am usign JsonPath for validating the resposen, thanks for mentioning that this trick works directely with jsonPath as below ==========================>JsonPath pastPartnerUsersListResponseJson= pastPartnerUsersListResponse.getBody().jsonPath();
String pendingCcoId=   pastPartnerUsersListResponseJson.getList("data.findAll{it.accessOrder==1}.ccoId").stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0).toString(); I have one basic question here, what is that it, you used , how is it used

Comment: Later to this party, Rest-Assured JsonPath is actually Groovy Path...